# Can't enable/disable ACE inheritance with SetAccessRuleProtection()

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to enable/disable inheritance

```
public static void test(string filename, bool enabled)
{
    FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
    security.SetAccessRuleProtection(enabled, enabled);
    File.SetAccessControl(filename, security);
}

// disable inheritance and copy existing ACEs
test(true, true);

// enable inheritance
test(false, false);
```

But it does not work, the ACE remains the same in explorer.

What was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me on Windows 10, although you surely mean `test("filename.txt", true)` not `test(true, true)` don't you?  I'm wondering if you're looking in the right place for the inheritance??

The code at the bottom creates a test.txt file in the bin/debug folder of the project and calls your method on it.  It shows that the AreAccessRulesProtected flag goes from False before the call to True after it, meaning inheritance has been removed.

If I break on the line that calls test, that is, before it's called, and look at the file properties in Windows Explorer, Security/Users/Advanced, then I get a screen as below, which shows the permissions are inherited:
[image]

If I do the same thing after the call I get the screen below, which shows the inheritance has been removed:
[image]

The code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = "test.txt";
        File.Delete(fileName);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Hello World");
        bool rulesProtected = File.GetAccessControl(fileName).AreAccessRulesProtected;
        Console.WriteLine($"AccessRulesProtected before setting protection: {rulesProtected}");
        test(fileName, true);
        rulesProtected = File.GetAccessControl(fileName).AreAccessRulesProtected;
        Console.WriteLine($"AccessRulesProtected after setting protection: {rulesProtected}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void test(string filename, bool enabled)
    {
        FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
        security.SetAccessRuleProtection(enabled, enabled);
        File.SetAccessControl(filename, security);
    }
```